# Get form data from UI Modal in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I'm fairly new to Angular and Have created a Modal for Login. I'm trying to show the user input using alert window to check if my form data is sent to controller. The data is not being sent to controller. Below is the code.

login-popup.html

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!--<div class="modal-content">-->

        <!--Close Form Button-->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Log In</h4>
        </div>

        <!--Form Body-->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input ng-model="user.username" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--Login Button-->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="login(user)">Let's GO</button>
        </div>


    <!--</div>-->
</div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('LoginPage',['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('LoginController',['$scope','$uibModal', function($scope,$uibModal){
        $scope.name = 'a100';
        $scope.open = function(){
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                  animation: 'true',
                  templateUrl: 'login-popup.html',
                  controller: 'LoginModalController'
            });
        };
}]);

app.controller('LoginModalController',['$scope','$uibModalInstance',function($scope,$uibModalInstance, $modalInstance){
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.login = function(user){
        $scope.user = user;
        alert(user);
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    }
}]);
```

So, the alert(user) gives '`object object`' alert message in browser.
How do I get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

user is an object in this case. alert only displays text. You could do this:

```
alert('Username: ' + user.username + ' Password: ' + user.password);
```

Alternatively, if you are just doing this for testing, you could use:

```
console.log(user), which will give you an expandable object.
```

If you wanted to this the "angular" way then I suggest looking at $window and/or $log. Just for development, either way suffices.

**Window Alert**

```
$window.alert('Username: ' + user.username + ' Password: ' + user.password);
```

**Console Logging**

```
$log.debug(user), which will give you an expandable object.
```

- $window: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window
- $log: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log

Comment: When I do that, alert(user.username), it says 'undefined' in alert popup

Comment: What do you see with console.log(user); ?

Comment: Its an empty object in console. 'object {}'

Answer (score 0):

Approach, mentioned by @[brianslattery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4614870/brianslattery), should work, test code here
https://plnkr.co/edit/3MkHOx2fiHLYfHUPHLS8?p=preview

```
  $scope.login = function(user) {
    $scope.user = user;
    alert(user.username + " " + user.password);
    $uibModalInstance.close();
  }
```

The problem with username that you mentioned, is that you are using **type="email"**, and should enter valid email, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467508/is-there-an-ng-model-and-input-type-email-bug) post, so your model property will be updated.

```
<input ng-model="user.username" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="username" />
```